# Chart js with json file from url

Tags: chart.js

I am new here so please forgive my errors in asking. I am working on a personal project with json file from external url. But the graph does not shown up. Chrome compiler says that 
    Chart.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: t.ticks.map is not a function
    Chart.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefinedeventHandler @ Chart.min.js:12(anonymous function) @ Chart.min.js:12i.(anonymous function) @ Chart.min.js:12 
Note: Arrays are getting the values
    (Sorry if I ask this wrong way I will try to improve my questions)

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
        <script>
            var name;
            var count;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var jsonurl = "http://avare.pe.hu/veri2.json";

                $.getJSON(jsonurl, function (json) {


                    name = json[0]['names'];
                    count = json[0]['count'];
                    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        console.log(name[i] + count[i]);


                });
            })



            var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
            var dataSet = {
                labels: name,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "My First dataset",
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
                        hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
                        data: count,
                    }
                ]
            };
            var option = {
                animation: {
                    duration: 5000
                }

            };


            var myBarChart = Chart.Bar(canvas, {
                data: dataSet,
                options: option
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are creating your chart before you get the values, the creation of the chart should happen in the on success of the `getJSON` call other wise you are passing undefined data to your chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue comes from the async call to get the data. You start the chart initialization after this call but because it is async `name` and `count` will be `undefined` at the time you create the chart.

Quick fix is to place the chart creation inside the success callback of the `getJSON`

https://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/45x1f09v/

Comment: Thanks.Worked like a charm.

Comment: found this in May 2022. the fiddle is gone :(